# UIWebView loadString not working in storyboards prepareForSegue function?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uistoryboardsegue

I see online lot of examples with the `loadString` called to load static HTML into `UIWebView`.

I'm trying to build the same in a `prepareForSegue()` function of my app.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    MYCLASSController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fromListToDetail"]) {
        // let's suppose getHtmlTextForItem returns the NSString @"<b>Some HTML text</b> with formatting"       
        [destViewController.htmlText loadHTMLString: [db getHtmlTextForItem:bookId] baseURL:nil];
    }
}
```

But It doesn't load anything. Do you have any idea on how to solve this??? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the content in the viewDidLoad method of your class MYCLASSController.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
[UIWebViewInstance loadHTMLString: @"something" baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: Works in the viewDidLoad... But that's not what I need :)

Comment: Solved by passing the html text to an attribute of the viewcontroller class, and then loading the html in the viewDidLoad function.

Answer (score 1):

The web view is not instantiated until after your segue has been performed. You can confirm this in the debugger.

You should pass the HTML to the view controller as a string property, and then load it into the web view in viewDidLoad. It's a good general principle to only allow a view controller to manage its own views. External objects shouldn't be able to modify them. See [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/) fantastic article for more.